# Поиск отсутсвующих данных ORACLE

Tags: oracle, null

Из двух таблиц производится выборка.

В результате мы получаем некоторый результат НАЙДЕННЫХ данных.

Названия и количество столбцов в таблицах - одинаковое:

-username

-number

-start_date

В t1 к каждый номер имеет по 10-15 строк, в t2 - тысячи.

Из t1 мы берем каждую строку из столбца start_date и ищем ВСЕ данные из t2, попадающие в радиус +30 минут и -30 минут от этой даты из t1.

Суть в том, что результат выдает только найденные строки из t2, а может быть такое, что в этот радиус не входит ни одна строк из t1, тогда нужно вывести эту дату из t1 на экран и показать NULL значение из t2.

Как вывести и те даты из t1, которые не попали в этот радиус +- 30 минут из t2?

```
SELECT t1.username,
       t1.number,
       t1.start_date,
      ,listagg(to_char(t2.date_time, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS'), '; ') within group (order by t2.date_time) list_date
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.number='5646523' and t1.number=t2.number and t2.date_time BETWEEN (t1.date_time - (1/24/2)) and (t1.date_time + (1/24/2))
GROUP BY t1.username, t1.number, t1.start_date
```

Comment: забыть про древний как дерьмо мамонта comma-style JOIN и использовать явный - в данном случае требуется LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @Akina - Чем Вам не нравятся мамонты?  Всего-то хобот `(+)` нарисовать нужно

Comment: @ESkri , а можно пример кода с этим хоботом (+) ? 
Очень интересно, как это правильно выглядит.

Comment: @tennant993 - [ask tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=difference-join-between-and-notation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте **LEFT JOIN**

```
SELECT t1.username,
       t1.number,
       t1.start_date,
       listagg(to_char(t2.date_time, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS'), '; ') within group (order by t2.date_time) list_date
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.number=t2.number and t2.date_time BETWEEN (t1.date_time - (1/24/2)) and (t1.date_time + (1/24/2))
WHERE t1.number='5646523'
GROUP BY t1.username, t1.number, t1.start_date
```

Comment: Благодарю. Все работает.